# Turning a plot3 into a surf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have several csv files and I plotted them using plot3 to create the following image:

[image: first attempt]

Now I would like to turn this into a surface plot because I would like to colour the plot according to height. I made the following with scatter3:

```
clearvars;
files = dir('*.csv');
name = '\epsilon_{y} over time for Vertical section';
des_col_1 = 'Vertical section.epsY []';
des_col_2 = 'Length [mm]';
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
a = gca;
ii = 1;
x_data = [];
y_data = [];
z_data = [];
tStart = tic;
for file = files'
    csv = xlsread(file.name);
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(file.name);
    des_cols = {des_col_1,des_col_2};
    colhdrs = s(1,:);
    [~,ia] = intersect(colhdrs, des_cols);
    colnrs = flipud(ia);
    file.name = n(:,colnrs);
    file.name = file.name(1:end,:);
    x_data = [x_data; file.name(:,2)];
    y_data = [y_data; ones(size(file.name(:,2))).*ii];
    z_data = [z_data; file.name(:,1)];
    ii = ii+1;
end
tEnd = toc(tStart);
fprintf('%d minutes and %f seconds\n',floor(tEnd/60),rem(tEnd,60));
view(40,40);
zlabel({'True strain (%)'});
xlabel({'Length along sample (mm)'});
ylabel({'Stage'});
title({name});
scatter3(a,x_data,y_data,z_data,10,z_data);
colormap(jet); %# or other colormap
```

which gives me this

[image: second attempt]

That was made with a smaller set of data than the first one as a test. It does almost what I want but I was wondering if there was a way to generate a true 3D surface from all my data. I can create a matrix with x, y, and z values for all points and I tried to replace `scatter3(a,x_data,y_data,z_data,10,z_data);` with

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x_data,y_data);
f = scatteredInterpolant(x_data,y_data,z_data);
Z = f(X,Y);
surf(a,X,Y,Z);
```

but the plot that I get does not look very good

[image: third attempt]

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the interpolation but I'm not very good with surfaces so I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Is the `x_data` array the same in each file?  Same dimensions?  Same values?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same size but they have different values. Here is a link to some of the files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pmvl92c5xv31oiu/AADPDXmUBy3MFL7OyqzMwopIa?dl=0

Comment: This might be obvious but did you try just `surf(x_data,y_data,z_data)` just after your loop finished.  You don't have to have a perfect grid of X & Y for `surf` to work.  The faces of the surface might be a bit skewed depending on how varied the X-values are but worth a shot.

Comment: I tried it and I get

Error using surf (line 71)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

Comment: Well that is interesting looking at you code I would have assumed it was a matrix.  I think I know what is happening and will provide an answer shortly.  However, I won;t be able to test it because dropbox is currently blocked at my office so I can't get to your test files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `surf` is giving you the error is you are creating long nx1 arrays Where n = number of points per file times number of files.  For x,y,& z_data and you need them into a matrix instead.  So try the following changes:

```
for file = files'
    <snipped out for length>
    x_data = [x_data; file.name(:,2).'];
    y_data = [y_data; ones(1,numel(file.name(:,2))).*ii];
    z_data = [z_data; file.name(:,1).'];
    ii = ii+1;
end
```

This should make x, y, and z_data the size nxm  (n = number of files, m = number points per file).

Then you should be able to just do

```
surf(x_data,y_data,z_data)
```

Comment: Once again I owe you. That worked! I just had to make a small change:  
  
    `x_data = [x_data; file.name(:,2).'];`  
    ` temp = ones(size(file.name(:,2))).*ii;`  
    `temp = temp';`  
    `y_data = [y_data; temp];`  
    `z_data = [z_data; file.name(:,1).'];`  
  
Otherwise the matrices would be of different sizes.