# Matlab make plot3 look like surface plot

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors `x`, `y` and `z`. I am able to plot these points with `plot3` however I want it to be more fancy and filled with colors like how plots look 3 dimensional with `surf`. Actually, my aim was for it to be like that of a surf plot however I am unable to get the results I need with `surf`

This is what I currently have.

```
x = 0:90;
y = 0:4:360;
z = ones(size(x));
z(50) = 3.6;
z(80) = 2.8;
z(10) = 2;
plot3(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Does `mesh` do what you want?

Comment: I tried mesh, it said z must be a matrix.

Comment: What about changing the third line for `z = ones(numel(x),numel(y));` and the last one for `mesh(x,y,z)` (sorry, I don't have a matlab at hand)

Comment: Thank you :) This looks close but the peaks are only on the y-axis now, it is as if x = 0 for all the points.

Comment: What happens if you rotate the view? does it look like it is 2D or you see the 3D?

Comment: It remains the same with rotation. it looks like this https://imgur.com/NWMYfRS

Comment: The misconception here is, that `mesh` requires a matrix (for surface plots), but you provide a vector to it. With `z = ones(numel(x),numel(y));` you create a matrix with z values for each combination of `x` and `y`. `z(1,1)` corresponds to x=0, y=0. `z(end,end)` to x=90, y=360. By setting `z(50)=3.6` MATLAB uses linear indexing (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1301) and sets the 50th element to 3.6.  You might instead want to provide a second argument to define the y position (e.g. `z(10,10)=1`). Or to set the values along the whole y axis: `z(50,:)=3.6`.

Comment: Have you tried modifying a working example from the documentation for `surf`?  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a plot3 into a surf in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300723/turning-a-plot3-into-a-surf-in-matlab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300723/turning-a-plot3-into-a-surf-in-matlab?rq=1